# AngularJs Directive does not get called correctly when page change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, directive

I have a header in my app which uses a directive to show / hide links depending in the user permissions, this directive uses a service which return a resolved promise with boolean result. The problem is that the header navigation links are not showing / hiding correctly (it shows the previous user accessible links, so I'm assuming the service is not being called), when I'm debugging with the chrome console I expect some logs shown at the service or directive but there is nothing, the only way I see the logs is by reloading the page.

Directive:

```
.directive('hasAccess', ['PermissionsService', function( PermissionsService) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    requiredAccess: "@",
    requiredAccessFunc: '@'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    PermissionsService[scope.requiredAccessFunc](scope.requiredAccess, scope.locationId).then(function(bool) {
      console.log("hasAccess");
      if (!bool) {
        element.addClass('hidden');
      }
    }, function(error) {
      element.addClass('hidden');
    });
  }
};
}])
```

Service:

```
smps.checkSettingsAccess = function(settingName) {
  console.log("checkSettingsAccess");
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  UserFactory.get().$promise.then (function(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response[settingName]);
  }, function() {
    deferred.reject(response);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Header directive:

```
.directive('header', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: "directives/header.html",
  controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {

    }]
}
```

})

Header html:

```
<li><a has-access required-access="company_access" required-access-func="checkSettingsAccess" ng-href="#/company_info">Company</a></li>
<li><a has-access required-access="locations_access" required-access-func="checkSettingsAccess" ng-href="#/locations">Locations</a></li>
<li><a has-access required-access="staff_members_access" required-access-func="checkSettingsAccess" ng-href="#/staff_members">Staff</a></li>
<li><a has-access required-access="customers_access" required-access-func="checkSettingsAccess" ng-href="#/customers">Customers</a></li>
<li><a has-access required-access="online_scheduling_access" required-access-func="checkSettingsAccess">Online Scheduling</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directive watches on two variable in parent scope: 

  `scope: {
    requiredAccess: "@",
    requiredAccessFunc: '@'
  }`

If you want render the directive you should change this variable. Because your directive depends on internal state.

Comment: Those variables are strings which are used by the service, the requiredAccessFunc is the service function and the requiredAccess is the parameter for the function. I think the problem remains on the directive which is not be called when the page changes. How can I make it change without making changes on the two scope variables I have?

Comment: So i think you can use $render. here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: When I move the content of the header (the html) and put it on a view it just works, and I did not even reload the page, so I think the problem also could be related to the header directive which renders the header html, remember that the header is the one that calls the the directive through the dom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `smps.checkSettingsAccess` passes a `deferred.resolve();` or `deferred.reject();` but `.then(function(bool)` takes a bool, are you sure that's correct?  What is the value of `bool` in the the `then` function?  It may be an object and therefore always true?

I suggest that instead of just doing this:
`element.addClass('hidden');`
You do this:
`element.removeClass('hidden');`
and have all your HTML default things to `class='hidden'` because it's a security thing, should default to hidden while AJAX happens.

Comment: the smps.checkSettingsAccess function is manipulating a promise, so what I'm doing is returning a boolean true or false. The then(function(bool) is the result of calling the service function it could be a true or a false. I think you are not understanding the problem. My problem is that my directive is not being executed at all but ONLY when I reload the page manually.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done so far is:

1. Remove the hasAccess directive
2. Add the currentUser to the rootScope like: $rootScope.currentUser
3. Use the currentUser to ask if the given access is true (show) or if its false (hide)

I KNOW... it is not the best solution because it is a bit ugly, but at least it works.

What I need to understand is how to create a header directive that depends on injected services (the service uses ng-resource through the rootScope), the directive somehow should be able to reload or catchup when the rootScope.currentUser changes so it displays correctly the links in HTML.

Feel free to suggest improvements or any comments. Thanks!

```
    <li><a ng-show="currentUser['company_access']" ng-href="#/company_info">Company</a></li>
    <li><a ng-show="currentUser['locations_access']" ng-href="#/locations">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a ng-show="currentUser['staff_members_access']" ng-href="#/staff_members">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a ng-show="currentUser['customers_access']" ng-href="#/customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a ng-show="currentUser['online_scheduling_access']">Online Scheduling</a></li>
```